# Git compare sidebar missing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I used to have the sidebar (like in the image below) when I was comparing the differences in a file between two different commits, but now the bar is missing and I can't find a way to restore it, suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced
2. Tick: *Show the difference overview margin*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to turn on the scroll bar map mode. Here's the official doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-track-your-code-by-customizing-the-scrollbar?view=vs-2019

Comment: Noup unfortunately, those instructions are for these https://imgur.com/a/YWPNYv1